# Not getting correct expected output

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Given a number `d` and a number `n`.
I have to print all the combinations of length `n` such that first element is `d` and all other are
1 distance away from previous one.

E.g. For input `d=4 n=3`

Output

`4 3 2
 4 3 4
 4 5 4
 4 5 6`

I wrote following code but it is displaying every line twice as follows -

`4 3 2
 4 3 2
 4 3 4
 4 3 4
 4 5 4
 4 5 4
 4 5 6
  4 5 6`

Code -

```
private static void printNumbers(int d, int n, String comb) {
    if(n == 0) {
        System.out.println(comb);
        return;
    }

    printNumbers(d-1, n-1, comb+d+"\t");
    printNumbers(d+1, n-1, comb+d+"\t");
}
```

and method call looks like -

```
 printNumbers(4,3,"");
```

I tried to debug but was not able to come up with the test condition for not having duplicate output.
I understand we can use `Set` or similar DS to avoid duplicates, but I am wondering if there is solution without using extra space.

Comment: imagine you are in the recursive call and n=1 comb ="xxxxx" and d = 2 e.g.  What would your printNumbers function do in this case?

Comment: See the question description if `n=1` `comb` will never be more than 1 in length also comb always starts with `d`

Comment: thats not true... since your recursion decrease n and increse the length of comb... comb ="xxxx" was meant as placeholder. as i said: imagine you are **in** the recursion... means it is not the initial call... Anyway.. my question was directed to the fact, that i didnt want to present you the answer, rather let you discover it for yourself. It is the exact example the accepted answer hints to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when `n == 1`, you call:

```
printNumbers(d-1, 0, comb+d+"\t");
printNumbers(d+1, 0, comb+d+"\t");
```

which will print the string twice.

You can easily remedy this by changing your stopping criterion:

```
private static void printNumbers(int d, int n, String comb) {
    if(n == 1) {
    //      ^ change here
        System.out.println(comb + d);
        //                      ^ change here
        return;
    }

    printNumbers(d-1, n-1, comb+d+"\t");
    printNumbers(d+1, n-1, comb+d+"\t");
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. You're awesome..!!